# Is there any way to access a managed meta data service using only javascript in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: javascript, taxonomy, client-object-model

I am creating custom forms in a SharePoint site. The only thing is most of our Lists contain managed metadata fields.

I have been successful in adding new items to Lists having only standard fields by way of WCF services, but these services don't appear to handle Managed Metadata fields OOB.

And I'm restricted to using only OOB technology, so no Visual Studio.

any ideas ?

Comment: Well, if exposed via ASMX ...

Comment: I actually am trying to put together a solution using asmx web services, but I keep getting a 400 Bad Request error.

I've been looking all over for an example of using Copy.asmx CopyIntoItems to upload a document to a document library. All the examples I can find are written in C#. :|

I think it that my SOAP envelope has an error somewhere. 

In the <stream> value, I have it set to base64binary encoding. Also, my destination url is form as follows:

http://[server]/[subsite/Demo_DocList1/Sample1.txt

with my source being C:\\Sample1.txt

Comment: Start with something like [STORM](http://storm.codeplex.com/) (or perhaps WCF STORM?) and craft some simple requests. Then the requests/responses can be tested and the complexity can be continuously expanded into success or ... not possible :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SharePoint 2010, you are in luck!

You have 4 options:

1. Use the Client Object Model provide by SharePoint Foundation 2010 CSOM

   Since you cannot use managed code (.NET code), your option of using managed .NET Object Model is out of question. Same with the managed Silverlight Object Model. You might be able to use the JavaScript object model for most of the things you are asking.
2. Use the REST API provided by SPF 2010 CSOM

   This provides a subset of Client Object Model functionality, but this will do what you want.
3. Create a custom WCF RESTful Service, hosted in the SPF 2010 server.

   This will require more work. It is more complex. But, again it will do what you want.
4. Use the ASP.NET Web Services

   These are legacy asmx services that were also available in SharePoint 2007. MS recommendation is that use only these services for backward compatibility. In other words, avoid using them in new solutions.

Based on your question, I will choose option #1. If that does not meet your needs choose option #2, then #3.

The SharePoint SDK provides good documentation on this this. Check out the following section: [Using the SharePoint Foundation Client APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537564.aspx) More specifically, take a look at the following section: [JavaScript Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185006.aspx)

The [MS Developing SharePoint 2010 Applications Guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798452.aspx) provides good documentation on this topic as well. More specifically, check out the section titled: "Using the REST Interface"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about listdata service. But surely you can do so by using Client Object Model. if Client OM is an option, you can see the link http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-attach-files-to.html

Hops its help