# How to access the TermSets of Metadata service using Client Object Model of SharePoint 2010 Programatically?

Tags: client-object-model, metadata

I want to know how i can find names of  the metadata services available on the particular site, and if those services are available.

Also how can i access the TermSets of the metadata services using Client Object Model of SharePoint 2010 in C#?

Comment: Afaik most service applications are not available through the client object model, or in a limited way. But you could always create a webservice yourself and call that in your client side code. The server side model for the term store is pretty well documented.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check if the Managed Metadata Service is available and have access to the server, the easiest way is to use PowerShell:

```
Get-SPServiceApplication | ? { $_.TypeName -eq "Managed Metadata Service"}
```

If you want to see if the service is online check the Status property in the output of this cmdlet

```
Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | ? { $_.TypeName -eq "Managed Metadata Service Connection"}  | fl *
```

Regarding your question on Taxonomies and Client Object Model, check out this question asked earlier [Is there any way to access a managed meta data service using only javascript in SharePoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25415/is-there-any-way-to-access-a-managed-meta-data-service-using-only-javascript-in)